# Remove rows from child table with Class Table Inheritance in Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, single-table-inheritance

I have made a really basic example with two models.

> "Singer" extends from "Person"

I am using [class table Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) with these two models:

```
<?php
namespace models;

/**
 * @Table(name="persons")
 * @entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"singer" = "\models\Singer"})
 */
abstract class Person {

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false, name="id_person")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @column(type="string", nullable=false) */
    protected $name;
```

The singer model looks like:

```
namespace models;

/**
 * @Table(name="singers")
 * @entity
 */
class Singer extends Person{

    /** @column(type="string", nullable=false) */
    protected $gender;
}
```

#### Workflow

Consider this scenario.

1. In the db I have these rows:

   persons table:

   ```
   id_person | name | type
   -----------------------
   1           john   singer
   ```

   singers table:

   ```
   id_person | gender
   ------------------
   1           pop
   ```
2. I proceed to remove this singer:

   ```
   $singer = $em->find('models\Singer', 1);
   $em->remove($singer);
   $em->flush();
   ```
3. After execute the code above, I check again the database and I found this:

   persons table:

   ```
   id_person | name | type
   -----------------------
   (empty)
   ```

   singers table:

   ```
   id_person | gender
   ------------------
   1           pop
   ```

   As you note, the row from child table was not removed as expected.
4. So, after searching in doctrine's documentation, it states:

   > When you do not use the SchemaTool to generate the required SQL you should know that deleting a class table inheritance makes use of the foreign key property ON DELETE CASCADE in all database implementations. A failure to implement this yourself will lead to dead rows in the database.

   So, I proceed to alter persons table as below:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE persons 
   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_persons_1
   FOREIGN KEY (id_person)
   REFERENCES singers (id_person)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
   ```

Now, the problems get complicated:

- when I remove a singer, the information still there, even the persons table was altered in order to delete from singers table too.
- When I try to insert a new singer like

  ```
  $singer = new \models\Singer('Zara', 'rock');
  $em->persist($singer);
  $em->flush();
  ```

  it throws an exception:

  ```
  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`practica`.`persons`, CONSTRAINT `fk_persons_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_person`) REFERENCES `singers` (`id_person`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION)' in /var/www/html/doctrine/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php:138 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/doctrine/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php(138): PDOStatement->execute(NULL) #1 /var/www/html/doctrine/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/JoinedSubclassPersister.php(165): Doctrine\DBAL\Statement->execute() #2 /var/www/html/doctrine/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php(929): Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\JoinedSubclassPersister->executeInserts() #3 /var/www/html/doctrine/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php(318): Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->executeInserts(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)) #4 /var/www/html/doctrine/vendor/doct in /var/www/html/doctrine/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php on line 47
  ```

So, basically, all I need is to remove the information in child table too in MySQL db. But I do not get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reversing the `FOREIGN KEY` i.e. remove it from your persons table and add it to your singers table

```
ALTER TABLE singers 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_singers_1
FOREIGN KEY (id_person)
REFERENCES persons (id_person)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: it worked like a charm. I thought that I had to light 7 candles and dancing under the full moon.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably have to ask yourself if you really need a field relating to multiple tables.

In any case, maybe is better to do it through a relation instead of using inheritance and a discriminator map, that works well with objects using the same table, but since in your case they are different tables it is probably better to use a relation instead:

```
<?php
namespace models;

/**
 * @Table(name="persons")
 * @entity
 */

class Person {

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false, name="id_person")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @column(type="string", nullable=false) */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Singer")
     * @JoinColumn(name="id_person", referencedColumnName="id_person")
     */
    private $singer;


namespace models;

/**
 * @Table(name="singers")
 * @entity
 */
class Singer{

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false, name="id_person")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @column(type="string", nullable=false) */
    protected $gender;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Person", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @JoinColumn(name="id_person", referencedColumnName="id_person")
     */
    private $person;
}
```

By trying to attach the design to the real world you are over complicating the implementation which will make your application hard to mantain.
I did not try the code (probably needs adjustement).

Comment: Hello, I am sure of all architecture's implications of this design carry on, however your solution demands change the logic from "table inheritance" to "association" and that is not the point.

Comment: From my experience "table inheritance" is going to give you more headaches than solutions. 
Still, if you want to go with this approach I suggest you to move the "type" to another table, otherwise you will find yourself changing your code every time you want to add a new type.